# Getting error in Oracle "ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into..." when there are no NULL values

Tags: php, sql, oracle, datatable, insert

I am currently trying to execute below code on Oracle SQL:

```
INSERT INTO author (totalrevenue)

SELECT NVL (margin, 0)
FROM (SELECT a.author_Fname, a.author_lname, SUM (b.totalmargin) as margin 
FROM author a LEFT JOIN bookauthor ba ON a.author_id = ba.ba_authorid
LEFT JOIN book b ON ba.ba_isbn = b.book_isbn
GROUP BY a.author_fname, a.author_lname);
```

The SELECT query returns a column of 14 values that are NOT NULL, achieved by using the `NVL`.

However, I still get that: *"ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("IT337052"."AUTHOR"."AUTHOR_ID")"* error when I execute the `INSERT` query together with the `SELECT` query.

Any ideas please?

Comment: But you provide no value for the AUTHOR_ID column...

Comment: You should do `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`, since the authors already exist in the table!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs to be an UPDATE (or MERGE) statement. I suspect your original attempt at the update statement failed because you didn't correlate the subquery to the table you're updating.

I think you're after something like:

```
UPDATE author a
SET    totalrevenue = (SELECT SUM(b.totalmargin) AS margin
                       FROM   bookauthor ba
                              LEFT JOIN book b ON ba.ba_isbn = b.book_isbn
                       WHERE  a.authorid = ba.ba_authorid)
WHERE  totalrevenue != (SELECT SUM(b.totalmargin) AS margin
                        FROM   bookauthor ba
                               LEFT JOIN book b ON ba.ba_isbn = b.book_isbn
                        WHERE  a.authorid = ba.ba_authorid);
```

I've added the where clause to avoid updating rows that already have the correct value. You could exclude it, but if you did, it would mean every row in the author table would be updated, even if the value was already correct - i.e. more work may be done than is necessary. If, however, you have created this column and need to populate it for the first time, you wouldn't need the where clause since you need to update every row anyway.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment. But I get this error: "SQL Error: ORA-00938: not enough arguments for function"... your SELECT query returns the correct table so no idea what is going on

Comment: Oops, sorry; you just need to remove the coalesce entirely. I forgot to put the second argument in to make it 0, but if the value is null, it won’t be picked up by the sum anyway. I’ve updated my answer.

Comment: Solved. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

it seems you missed AUTHOR_ID in data inserttion

```
INSERT INTO author (AUTHOR_ID,totalrevenue)

SELECT AUTHOR_ID,NVL (margin, 0)
FROM (SELECT a.AUTHOR_ID , SUM (b.totalmargin) as margin 
FROM author a LEFT JOIN bookauthor ba ON a.author_id = ba.ba_authorid
LEFT JOIN book b ON ba.ba_isbn = b.book_isbn
GROUP BY a.AUTHOR_ID);
```

Comment: In such case you don't need to group by a.author_fname, a.author_lname becasue you're using AUTHOR_ID which seems to be a primary key. Query is really strange because it's trying to insert total revenue for authors instead of an updated

Comment: @SergeyM this is not mysql it is oracle

Comment: what's difference if we are speaking about SQL in general. You don't need  a.author_Fname, a.author_lname at all. It is not used anywhere and AUTHOR_ID will perfrom grouping on much granular level then other useless columns

Comment: @SergeyM do some R&D bro you will find the rest

Comment: I think you didn't get my point. I mean you don't need a.author_fname, a.author_lname columns in group by as well as in select. If you're taking a grouping logic by a.AUTHOR_ID then only a.AUTHOR_ID should be in select list with an aggregates. a.author_fname, a.author_lname become useless in this query.
I'm not a mysql expert that's why I know nothing about it's group by extensions. I'm speaking about sql standard

Comment: @SergeyM ah got it now yah that is absolutely correct and i edited thanks

Comment: But thank you Zaynul. Now I know something more about Group by and MySql stuff. Cheers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193516/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-sergey-m).

Comment: And my two cents more again. I think that your query will fail with exception if AUTHOR_ID is primary key because it will try to insert values with the same keys....

Answer (score 1):

One idea I have that your trying to insert new values in Author table that has a primary key AUTHOR_ID which cannot be null and it is not autoincremented by default. You have to provide primary key value explicitly

And I'm pretty interested why are you trying to insert new values when your calculations based on existed values and you'd like to calculate total for existed authors. 
Something wrong with a flow. 
You should use UPDATE or INSERT into some new table with totals. But not in the same as you use in selects

Comment: Hi and thanks for the idea, and you are right to point that out. I initially tried using UPDATE since all I am intending to  do is replace values in author.totalrevenue with the NVL (margin,0) value acquired from performing INNER JOIN and GROUP BY of three different tables. It didnt work, I get "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row" error... even though there are exactly the same number of values..